# How can i get back certificate detail from loaded certificate in SSL Context?

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I have loaded certificate into SSL context using `SSL_CTX_use_Cert()`.
in `SSL_ctx` where it is stored?

In `certstore` or In `cert` ?

I have am getting `NULL` in `certstore->objs`.
but I am getting some data in `cert->key->x509`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the openssl source code here https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/ssl_rsa.c

It is stored in `ctx->cert->pkeys[i].x509` where `i` is the type of public key